# Parse log on Bash - one result per second

Tags: bash, parsing, logging

I spent several days for this simple issue and can't get solition!

I have a log, and there are several rows per second. I need only one row per second - and it isn't matter, which one.

Example log:

```
23:59:58 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC 
23:59:58 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC
23:59:58 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC 
23:59:59 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC 
23:59:59 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC 
23:59:59 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC
```

I need this:

```
 23:59:58 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC 
 23:59:59 Incoming packet DeviceId:42FF223F23AC
```

I tried `cat log | uniq -w8`, but it doesn't work

I'm very sorry of my English - it's not my native language.
P.S. Solution on another script language (like PHP, Python) is fine too

Comment: Does this do it `cat inputFile | sort | uniq -w8` ?

Comment: sort + uniq -u doesn't work :(

Comment: It does work with the sample you provided, please [edit] your question to reflect that.

Comment: Your provided input have spaces at the end, only the `2nd` row does not. Therefore `sort -u your_input_file` does not give the expected answer since in this context `row 1` and `row 2` are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cat inputFile | sort | uniq -w8
```

or

```
sort inputFile | uniq -w8
```

As `uniq` is only comparing the first 8 characters, which are `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Cat is not necessary, `sort inputFule | uniq -w8` would do too. Anyway that is the solution. :)

Comment: Thank you! it's a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If the time field is the only thing you need to consider to determine if a line is different from the previous line, you could do it with this oneliner awk:

```
awk -F ' '  '{if ($1 != time_prev) {print $0;} time_prev=$1}' < yourfile.txt
```